# Executing shell commands on linux using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, command-line

I have a scenario in my webapp where i want to execute some shell command on the client , so is their any way i can achieve this using javascript. Their is a method "exec" in php but i think that will execute command at the server end.

Thanks in Advance,
Vinay

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If it was it would be a major security risk.

Comment: If you write a plugin for the browsers and let people install it, it might be possible. You cannot do this out of the box in any case because it would be considered a fatal security leak rather then a feature.

Comment: Hmm, hold on, do you mean: 'I want to write a command in the client and run it on the server'?

Comment: no i want to execute some commands on client machine like a simple ls on client or ifconfig.

Comment: why to down vote this question. Please stop downvoting for these type of questions and try to give some guidelines

Comment: Ah then no, not possible and if you do find a way, it's considered hacking and criminal in quite a lot of countries I think =P

Comment: If you find a way to do this, you may call yourself a hacker. If you exploit it you may call yourself a prison inmate:) its not illegal as long as you dont use it...and even that it depends how you use it

Comment: @Bala: I've downvoted this question because of (read BGerrissen's and Quamis' comment)

Answer (score 3):

No, JavaScript does not have access to the client machine, and certainly cannot execute shell commands. While this may be unfortunate for your genuine requirement, this is an important limitation for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

No, javascript cannot execute a command on the client-side. You could probably use an activeX control or a custom extension for Firefox... but its complicated:)

Comment: Is their any way by which i can run commands at client other than using activeX object.

Comment: well, one of the "features" of the web browser is to protect the user from getting "raped" by a malicious web page:) So..no. You may try and exploit IE6's bug though:)

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript can not do that but you can call server-side script, PHP for example, using Ajax request and pass command to it as a parameter, PHP script would retrieve the command and execute with `exec()` function.

P.S. bad practice...

Comment: can i do it by using servlets too...?